# Django Media File is not found on production (404)

Tags: django, nginx

I have wondered around lot of other stackoverflow issues to see if there is a solution but i couldn't work around it. So here is the issue:

Nginx.conf

```
  location /media/  {
        alias /root/server/media/;   
 }

   
  location /static/ {
        alias /root/server/static/;
    }
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

wsgi.py

```
application = WhiteNoise(application, root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))
application = WhiteNoise(application, root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'))
```

I have set everything as necessary, i check the directory (root/server/media) and images are there. But when i enter the link : $serverlink/media/images/1.png , it gives me 404 (Not found) error. Does anybody know why?

Update:

[image]

Comment: What is `root`? The root of your program, or a directory from the *root* of your filesystem?

Comment: directory of my filesystem ( root/django_project)

Comment: but is it a *root* directory? So it has *no* parent directory?

Comment: You can see it in update.

Comment: Do you want to manage static & media content with Nginx or Django ? Do you have tried without location from Nginx conf ?

Comment: I need to do it with Nginx because i am in production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing the trailing slash after media?

`location /media  { alias /root/server/media;    }`